# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

stored Procedure

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertLoanMaster]
   @TAc_no bigint
   ,@TAcc_no bigint
  ,@TAc_name nvarchar(50)
  ,@TV_no bigint
  ,@TJlg_no bigint
  ,@TPost_no bigint
  ,@TPhone_no1 bigint
  ,@TAct_no bigint
  ,@TLoan_amt bigint
  ,@TLoan_date date
  ,@TInt_rate bigint
  ,@TPay_mode nvarchar(max)
  ,@TPrin_inst nvarchar(max)
  ,@TGuar_name1 nvarchar(50)
  ,@TGuar_name2 nvarchar(50)
  ,@TChq_no bigint
 ,@TChq_date date
  ,@TGurAdd1 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurAdd2 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurPhone1 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurPhone2 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TPeriodInYear nvarchar(100)
  ,@TPeriod nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
insert Loan_Master (Ac_no,Acc_no , Ac_name,V_no,Jlg_no,Post_no,Act_no,phone_no1,Guar_name1,GurAdd1,GurPhone1,Guar_name2,GurAdd2,GurPhone2,Loan_amt,Loan_date ,Int_rate,PeriodInYear,Pay_mode,Prin_inst,Chq_date ,Chq_no,Period)values
(
   @TAc_no
  ,@TAcc_no
  ,@TAc_name
  ,@TV_no
  ,@TJlg_no
  ,@TPost_no
  ,@TPhone_no1
  ,@TAct_no
  ,@TLoan_amt
  ,@TLoan_date
  ,@TInt_rate
  ,@TPay_mode
  ,@TPeriodInYear 
  ,@TPrin_inst
  ,@TGuar_name1
  ,@TGuar_name2
  ,@TChq_no
  ,@TChq_date
  ,@TGurAdd1
  ,@TGurAdd2
  ,@TGurPhone1
  ,@TGurPhone2,
   @TPeriod)
```

END

call this procedure

```
    public void getInsert(Int64 Acno,Int64 Accno, string Acname, Int64 Vno, Int64 Jlgno, Int64 Postno, Int64 Actno, Int64 phoneno1, string Guarname1, string Guradd1, string  GurPh1, string Guarname2, string Guradd2, string  GurPh2,Int64 Loanamt, DateTime Loandate,Int64 Intrate, string  PeriodYear, string Paymode, string   Prininst, Int64 Chqno,DateTime Chqdate,string   period1)
    {
            conobj.getconnection();
            conobj.con.Open();
            conobj.cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertLoanMaster", conobj.con);
            conobj.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TAc_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Acno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TAcc_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Accno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TAc_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Acname;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TV_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Vno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TJlg_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Jlgno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPost_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Postno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TAct_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Actno;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPhone_no1", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = phoneno1;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGuar_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Guarname1;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGurAdd1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Guradd1;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGurPhone1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GurPh1;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGuar_name2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Guarname2;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGurAdd2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Guradd2;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TGurPhone2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GurPh2;
             conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TLoan_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Loandate; 
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TLoan_amt", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Loanamt;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TInt_rate", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Intrate;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPeriodInYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PeriodYear;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPay_mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Paymode;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPrin_inst", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = Prininst;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TChq_no", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Chqno;
                conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TChq_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Chqdate;
            conobj.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TPeriod", SqlDbType.NVarChar  ).Value = period1;
            conobj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conobj.con.Close();

    }
```

form Coding

```
   private void btnNewSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
        if (CMB_VillageNum.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            s = CMB_VillageNum.Items[CMB_VillageNum.SelectedIndex].ToString ();
        }
        string s1 = "";
        if (CMB_JLGNum.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            s1 = CMB_JLGNum.Items[CMB_JLGNum.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
        string s2 = "";
        if (CMB_ActiviNum.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            s2 = CMB_ActiviNum.Items[CMB_ActiviNum.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
        string s3 = "";
        if (CMB_PostNum.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            s3 = CMB_PostNum.Items[CMB_PostNum.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
        string s4 = "";
        if (CMB_Period.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            s4 = CMB_Period.Items[CMB_Period.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }

        //if (CMB_Period.SelectedIndex == 1)
        //{
       //string dateof = this.dateTimePicker1.Text;
       //string dateto =this. dateTimePicker2.Text;
        //objLoan.getInsert(Convert.ToInt64(txtAccNo.Text), txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt64(CMB_VillageNum.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt64(CMB_JLGNum.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt64(CMB_PostNum.SelectedValue)
        //                 , Convert.ToInt64(CMB_ActiviNum.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text), txtGurName1.Text, txtGurName2.Text, txtPhoneNum1.Text, txtPhoneNum2.Text, txtGur1Addresss.Text, txtGur2Addresss.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text), Convert.ToInt64(txtLoanAmt.Text), Convert.ToInt64(txtRateOfInter.Text)
        //                 , "0", txtPaymentMode.Text, txtPriInstall.Text, Convert.ToInt64(txtChequeNo.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text), txtPeroid.Text);
        //dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd//MM//yyyy");
        //dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd//MM//yyyy");

            objLoan.getInsert(Convert.ToInt64(txtAccNo.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToInt64(lblAccNum.Text.Trim()), txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt64(s.Trim()), Convert.ToInt64(s1.Trim()), Convert.ToInt64(s3.Trim())
                , Convert.ToInt64(s2.Trim()), Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text.Trim()), txtGurName1.Text, txtGur1Addresss.Text
                                    , txtPhoneNum1.Text, txtGurName2.Text, txtGur2Addresss.Text, txtPhoneNum2.Text
                                    , Convert.ToInt64(txtLoanAmt.Text.Trim()), Convert .ToDateTime (dateTimePicker1 .Text ),Convert.ToInt64(txtRateOfInter.Text.Trim()),(s4.Trim()), txtPaymentMode.Text,
                                     txtPriInstall.Text, Convert.ToInt64(txtChequeNo.Text.Trim()), Convert .ToDateTime (dateTimePicker2 .Text ),txtPeroid.Text);
```

I'm trying to call this procedure with the usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllbyId 42747, NULL command.

But I always get an error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure
>   usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllById, Line 9 Error converting data type
>   varchar to bigint.

The ID of TimesheetsAudits table is a bigint type. I tried several types of conversions and casts, but I'm really stuck right now.

Comment: Can you at least do some diagnostic work to narrow down which parameter is causing the problem?

Comment: Your posted stored procedure code is `spInsertLoanMaster`, but the error message is referencing `usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllById`.....I'd suggest looking at that stored procedure (where the error is being reported) and the code that is calling it.

Comment: Your insert statement is not matching up (columns vs values). I've found a few mismatches, but I'm sure you can find them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters in the insert of your stored procedure do not match the variables passed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Insert` Query and `Value` query having different order of `Parameters` and this caused issue the `Insert` statement. Try this for your `Insert` query,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertLoanMaster]
   @TAc_no bigint
   ,@TAcc_no bigint
  ,@TAc_name nvarchar(50)
  ,@TV_no bigint
  ,@TJlg_no bigint
  ,@TPost_no bigint
  ,@TPhone_no1 bigint
  ,@TAct_no bigint
  ,@TLoan_amt bigint
  ,@TLoan_date date
  ,@TInt_rate bigint
  ,@TPay_mode nvarchar(max)
  ,@TPrin_inst nvarchar(max)
  ,@TGuar_name1 nvarchar(50)
  ,@TGuar_name2 nvarchar(50)
  ,@TChq_no bigint
 ,@TChq_date date
  ,@TGurAdd1 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurAdd2 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurPhone1 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TGurPhone2 nvarchar(100)
  ,@TPeriodInYear nvarchar(100)
  ,@TPeriod nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN --Act_no
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
insert Loan_Master 
(
 Ac_no, Acc_no , Ac_name, V_no, Jlg_no, Post_no, Act_no, phone_no1, 
 Guar_name1 ,GurAdd1, GurPhone1, Guar_name2, 
 GurAdd2, GurPhone2, Loan_amt, Loan_date, Int_rate, 
 PeriodInYear, Pay_mode, Prin_inst, Chq_date, Chq_no, Period
)
values
(
 @TAc_no, @TAcc_no, @TAc_name, @TV_no, @TJlg_no, @TPost_no, @TAct_no, @TPhone_no1,  
 @TGuar_name1, @TGurAdd1, @TGurPhone1, @TGuar_name2,
 @TGurAdd2, @TGurPhone2, @TLoan_amt, @TLoan_date, @TInt_rate, 
 @TPeriodInYear, @TPay_mode, @TPrin_inst, @TChq_date, @TChq_no,  @TPeriod
)
```